# How to disable and re-enable tabindex of hidden/visible elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change the `tabindex` of an element based on whether or not the element is visible (in view-able area)? I would like to do one of these things: reset the current `tabindex` upon entering a new section and assign new `tabindex`'s to the elements in that section.  Or be able to disable and re-enable `tabindex`'s of certain elements.

html:

```
    <div id="nav">
        <a id="firstLink" href="#section1" tabindex="1">Go to section 1</a>
        <a id="secondLink" href="#section2" tabindex="2">Go to section 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="section1">
            <a href="#" tabindex="3">Specific to section 1</a>
        </div>
        <div id="section2">
            <a href="#" tabindex="3">Specific to section 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want the links to be in the tabbing order ONLY if their section is visible.

css:

```
    #container{
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }

    #section1{
        background: red;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }

    #section2{
        background: green;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }
```

​
Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/2UF3n/5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dynamically add or remove `disabled="disabled"` from any hidden field to make its `tabindex` value ignored.

```
$("a:hidden").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Comment: but what if I'm not using the `hidden` attribute.  In my example its a container with `overflow:hidden`.  Could you rework my example to show me how that could be incorporated?

Comment: You will need some distinction to select the hidden elements, in that case because there's no way to pick up on links that aren't shown due to overflow: hidden; without doing position checks...which I think is more a pain in the butt than you want to deal with.  The :hidden selector in jQuery will select items that take up no space in the document, but overflow: hidden; does not accomplish that; they still take up space, you just can't see it.  I would suggest hiding the elements you don't need visible via CSS or jQuery and not use overflow: hidden;.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but in my actual project I have a good deal of animations that rely on `overflow:hidden`. I'll try some different selectors out and use the `disabled` attribute as you suggested.

Comment: Doesn't work for divs. E.g. when using semantic-ui's dropdowns.

Comment: @TammyShipps , is it still true with modern browsers that this will not work with `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: @avalanche1  Well, no, of course not.  You can't disable a plain div with no function.  The disabled flag is for functional elements like anchors and form inputs.